# CardView button and text not aligning

Tags: android, material-design

I'm having a problem creating a CardView with a button that aligns to the start of the text:

[image: Screenshot of CardView with issue]

I'm following the dimensions set out in the Material Design spec for the padding and text-sizes. This is the XML I'm using:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="24dp"
            android:text="Title goes here"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text_default_material_light"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:text="Subtitle here"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Button
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="Action 1"
            android:textColor="@color/accent_material_light" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Visually, there's a gap between the start of the text and borderless button text.

[image]

As shown in the [Material Design spec](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html#cards-content-blocks), the button and the start of the title and subtitle should line up:

[image: Material design cardview showing aligned text and button]

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the android:layout_margin and android:padding attributes and replace with android:paddingLeft="8dp" as shown below. You should also consider using android:paddingStart to better support right to left layouts and using android:paddingRight and android:paddingEnd to better support right to left symmetry.

```
    <Button
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:text="Action 1"
        android:textColor="@color/accent_material_light" />
```

Comment: Looks ugly when button is highlighted (ripple effect).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the gravity of the button

```
android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
```

Comment: I just tried this and I noticed that if the button text is of short length, then the padding becomes unbalanced on either side, leading to the same problem where there is no vertical keyline alignment

Answer (score 0):

try 
  android:paddingLeft="0dp"

Comment: what happens if you remove the button android:layout_margin="8dp"?

Comment: The button becomes too left aligned